# Excluding a unit test of a particular file using maven

Tags: java, maven

I am working on a project, which I recently got and while running unit tests using `mvn test`.

So, I go to different modules and run the above command using cmd and **while doing so I came to know that there are two test cases in 2 files, which are failing intermittently** (this was mentioned in the comments above that methods).

So, I am thinking of skipping those test cases only and proceeding ahead for now. I tried to find it here but only thing I could find her is excluding test cases of a particular module.

I want to exclude test1() of A.java and test2() of B.java

I found below:

```
# Exclude one test method 
mvn verify -Dtest=!LegacyTest#testFoo
# Exclude two test methods
mvn verify -Dtest=!LegacyTest#testFoo+testBar
```

in [this](https://blog.jdriven.com/2017/10/run-one-or-exclude-one-test-with-maven/) link, but not sure how correct above method is and how to use it in my case, since I have not used maven before

Commands I have tried:

```
mvn verify -X -Dtest=!A#test1,!B#test2
mvn test -X -Dtest=!A#test1,!B#test2
```

**Error trace which I got after running above commands:**

```
[INFO] Selera Utils - Database ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 18.419 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-13T19:21:16+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/205M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project log4j: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this
 error.) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project log4j: No tests were exec
uted!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:748)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :log4j
```

Answer (score 2):

In the link, they say this following code run multiple test :

```
mvn test -Dtest=AppTest,Web*
```

So may be to exclude multiple :

```
mvn verify -Dtest=!A#test1,B#test2
```

I didn't try, but it seems logical.

**---EDIT---**
You can also use the plugin maven-surefire-plugin like [that](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html)

**---EDIT 2 ---**
I try and success, todo that verify in first that you use maven-surefire-plugin with version > 2.19 (add -X to get debug the version is printed); then your command will be :

```
mvn test -Dtest=!A#test1,!B#test2
```

Comment: I think the part after # is comment, so it will only interpret part till A and exclude all test cases in file A, which I don't want.... right?

Comment: If it was my own project I could have done that, but it is a running application in production and currently it is not using sunfire plugin, do you think including new plugins is a good idea just to skip few test cases ?

Comment: Yep I did try afterwards and added -X to get whole debug version, later on I got this: 'Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project log4j: No tests were executed!' which I believe because sunfire plugin is not there in project ??

Comment: Have you the line "Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0", if so it mean you exclude all possibles tests

Comment: Nope I did not find above line which you mentioned, I tried both commands you gave above, didn't work
Although it gave [this link](http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException) to get more details on the error thrown, which again tells the exception is due to plugin mainly not by maven core

Comment: Can you paste the maven build you get?

Comment: It was too long, so I added some part in question, is this the information you wanted ?

Comment: I obtain this kind of error when there are no tests to run, it's weird you don't have the line I spoke previously (even if it's not 0)

Comment: Yup, even I am not very sure about what's going on, since this application just came to me 1 month back and no one has good understanding of code, anyways....thanks for the effort :)

Comment: Good luck to find the solution !